# How to make a repeating CanvasGradient

Tags: html5-canvas

Is there any way to make a `CanvasGradient` that repeats?

I assume not, because I don't see any options on [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.createLinearGradient`](https://devdocs.io/dom/canvasrenderingcontext2d/createlineargradient) or `createRadialGradient` or any properties on [`CanvasGradient`](https://devdocs.io/dom/canvasgradient) that would apply

But I'm really surprised this feature would be missing given that CSS3 supports `repeating-linear-gradient` and `repeating-radial-gradient` background styles.

I have figured out a workaround for repeating linear gradients using `CanvasRenderingContext2D.createPattern` (see my answer below) but not a way to make a repeating radial gradient.

Answer (score 2):

For a linear gradient it's possible to create a pattern from the unit rectangle of the gradient:

```js
var tile = document.createElement('canvas')
tile.width = tile.height = 10
var tileCtx = tile.getContext('2d')
var gradient = tileCtx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, tile.width, tile.height)
gradient.addColorStop(0, 'red')
gradient.addColorStop(0.25, 'red')
gradient.addColorStop(0.25, 'blue')
gradient.addColorStop(0.5, 'blue')
gradient.addColorStop(0.5, 'red')
gradient.addColorStop(0.75, 'red')
gradient.addColorStop(0.75, 'blue')
gradient.addColorStop(1, 'blue') 
tileCtx.fillStyle = gradient
tileCtx.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10)

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
canvas.width = canvas.height = 200
canvas.style.width = canvas.style.height = '200px'
document.body.appendChild(canvas)
var context = canvas.getContext('2d')
context.fillStyle = context.createPattern(tile, 'repeat')
context.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200)
```

However, I don't know of a way to make a repeating radial gradient.