# How to convert repeating-linear-gradient of an element to a base64 image or any other format?

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image, html2canvas

I can't seem to find a way to convert the `repeat-linear-gradient` to a base64 image format.

```
background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent, transparent 5px, white 5px, white 10px);
```

My problem is I want to print an HTML page with `html2canvas` and `jsPDF` but since `html2canvas` doesn't support [support](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/features/) `repeat-linear-gradient`, I would like to know if there is a way to convert the value to base64.

Also, since the background image is rendered by the `gantt-chart` library, I can't change how it is set

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56398519/how-to-make-a-repeating-canvasgradient though the biggest problem would be parsing the CSS value. Does your viz-library produce a standard format?

Comment: updated my answer with a dynamic solution

Comment: @Kalido no, but i already have a way to parse the css but the problem is changing the format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's a repeating gradient, you can identify the smallest portion that you can export as image and that will allow you to have the same background by repeating this image.

You are dealing with `+-45deg` and the last color stop is `10px` so the smallest portion is `10px*sqrt(2) = 14.14px` for the height and width:

```css
.box {
  height: 14.14px;
  width: 14.14px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent, transparent 5px, blue 5px, blue 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

You save this as an image and you use any online tool that convert a png to base64:

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box" style="background:repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent, transparent 5px, blue 5px, blue 10px)"></div>
```

---

For a dynamic solution I will consider the code used in [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58885864/8620333)

```js
var box = document.querySelector(".box");

domtoimage.toPng(box)
  .then(function(dataUrl) {
    console.log(dataUrl)
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
        document.body.appendChild(image);
    };
    image.src = dataUrl;
  })
```

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  margin:5px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent, transparent 5px, blue 5px, blue 10px);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://css-challenges.com/wp-content/themes/ronneby_child/js/dom-to-image.js"></script>

<div class="box"></div>
```

Also like this:

```js
var box = document.querySelector(".box");

domtoimage.toPng(box)
  .then(function(dataUrl) {
    console.log(dataUrl);
    document.querySelector(".alt").style.background='url('+dataUrl+')';
  })
```

```css
.box {
  height: 14.14px;
  width: 14.14px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent, transparent 5px, blue 5px, blue 10px);
}

.alt {
  height:100px;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://css-challenges.com/wp-content/themes/ronneby_child/js/dom-to-image.js"></script>

<div class="box"></div>

<div class="alt"></div>
```

Comment: "You save this as an image and you use any online tool that convert a png to base64". I think that if they could do it, they wouldn't have their current problem to begin with. They are asking for a way to do it from the page itself, dynamically.

Comment: @Kaiido added a dynamic solution

Comment: @Temani thanks this works. but would've loved it if there was a native way to do it without loading up another library :)

Comment: @henokg you can always dig into how the library works (https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image#how-it-works) and try to write a minimal code that works for your case ;) (PS: don't forget to also upvote the answer if you found it useful :) )